# Can Moderators review more posts than the daily limit?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, review, moderators

Can moderators review unlimited posts in a single review queue within a day? I saw one moderator review more than 400 yesterday in Stack Overflow first posts review queue. Today also he's reviewed more than 100 since start.

[Here are the stats for today](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/stats). (Normal daily limit is 40 for Stack Overflow)

Is this available only for moderators or what is the logic behind this?